# pandas: loop over tables in excel sheet

Tags: excel, loops, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to loop over a set of tables in a particular way but I'm stuck.

My tables are multiindex and look like this:

```
#read excel 
df = pd.read_excel(data_file,
                   header=[0,1],
                   index_col=[0,1])

                           T        Gender                  Age                         
                         Total   Male Female 16-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-75 
Q1. Are you?  Yes         17.5   26.8   23.4  13.7  20.7   100     -  17.6    
              No          17.5   26.8   23.4  13.7  20.7   100  11.5  22.6 
              Don’t know  17.5   26.8   23.4  13.7  20.7   100     -     -
Q2. Are you?  Yes         18.5   26.8   23.4  13.7  20.7   100     -  17.6    
              No          17.5   22.8   23.4  13.7  20.7   100  11.5  22.6 
              Don’t know  17.5   26.8   23.4  13.7  20.7   100     -     -
```

I would like to loop over these indexes and columns and print this:

```
                           T                             
                          Total   
Q1. Are you?  Yes         17.5    
              No          17.5  
              Don’t know  17.5 

                            Gender                                              
                          Male Female 
Q1. Are you?  Yes         26.8   23.4  
              No          26.8   23.4  
              Don’t know  26.8   23.4
```

and so forth....

My code so far groups the outter indexs together which allows me to loop downwards but I dont know how to work my way across horizontally..?

```
for outerside_grp, innerside_grp in df.groupby(level=0):
    print innerside_grp
```

---

**UPDATE**

Code below kinda of does what I want (thanks to Joshua Baboo) but now I'm wondering if it's the most effient method?

```
for key in df.index.levels[0]:
    for col in df.columns.levels[0]:
        print df.loc[row:row, col]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you've said:

> 'My tables are multiindex'

assuming the `groupby(level=0)` is not required, as the original dataframe is in 2 level MultiIndex structure on both row & column axes, see if the following sample servers your purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
print 'pandas-version: ', pd.__version__
import numpy a`enter code here`s np
l1 = ['r0_1', 'r0_2']
l2 = sorted(['r1_1','r1_2','r1_3'])
c1 = ['c0_1', 'c0_2', 'c0_3']
c2 = ['c1_1', 'c1_2', 'c1_3']
nrows = len(l1) * len(l2)
ncols = len(c1) * len(c2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random( nrows * ncols).reshape(nrows, ncols),
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([l1, l2],
                                                 names=['one','two']),
                 columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c1, c2]))
l_all = slice(None)

# updated loop only over columns.level[0]
# to get all-rows for each column group
for col0 in df.columns.levels[0]:
    print df.loc(axis=1)[col0,:]
```

### output

```
pandas-version:  0.15.2
               c0_1                    
               c1_1      c1_2      c1_3
one  two                               
r0_1 r1_1  0.177051  0.159676  0.677900
     r1_2  0.980404  0.441649  0.763252
     r1_3  0.631876  0.724937  0.158891
r0_2 r1_1  0.856933  0.432360  0.690534
     r1_2  0.568308  0.381117  0.430071
     r1_3  0.680781  0.795433  0.378414
               c0_2                    
               c1_1      c1_2      c1_3
one  two                               
r0_1 r1_1  0.275005  0.266315  0.326656
     r1_2  0.841370  0.197737  0.215751
     r1_3  0.511860  0.007003  0.509688
r0_2 r1_1  0.170542  0.577844  0.616402
     r1_2  0.440131  0.497631  0.628281
     r1_3  0.061970  0.192166  0.687346
               c0_3                    
               c1_1      c1_2      c1_3
one  two                               
r0_1 r1_1  0.308490  0.372552  0.275818
     r1_2  0.718901  0.784083  0.839253
     r1_3  0.357739  0.821503  0.336578
r0_2 r1_1  0.758157  0.248164  0.983741
     r1_2  0.498885  0.972781  0.922519
     r1_3  0.107162  0.364109  0.591648
```

[ref for `.loc(axis=0)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/advanced.html)

Comment: Good idea, i'll try that today :)

Comment: got this error: KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

Comment: hi @Boosted_d16 did you get to resolve the error? which is the pandas version that you are using; I'm on pandas-version:  0.15.2

Comment: I'm on 0.16.2 and I managed to edit your method but it doesnt seem ideal.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 I've updated the code-snippet to loop-thru only the columns.levels[0] to get all rows for each column-group in source-data; I've also added documentation ref for further tweaking to get your exact format.